# Representing $\prod_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{k^{2}-1}\right)$ as an Euler's product.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, infinite-product, euler-product

The above formula corresponds to the following identity

$$
2=\prod_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{k^{2}-1}\right)
$$

I wonder if this can be represented as an Euler's product.

Could anyone find such a representation?

Thanks.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, I know this, but what I'm asking is if this can also be expressed as an infinit product over prime numbers.

Comment: @joriki: Oops. Of course. :) Actually, in light of the OP's comment, I've deleted both my comments.

Comment: I do not understand the question. Euler product is one which converts a series, i.e., a summation into a product of a similar summation over primes. Here you have a product, so could you be clear what you expect?

Comment: @user17762, suppose that this product is expanded into  an infinite  sum. My question is: Can we get an infinite product over primes, a kind of Euler's product like we have for $\pi^2/6$?

Comment: I mean $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^2-1}\right)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can expand your product as
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k\ge 2} \left(\frac{1}{1-k^{-2}}\right) &= \prod_{k\ge 2}\left(1+k^{-2}+k^{-4}+k^{-6}+\cdots\right) \\
& = 1 + \frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{2}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{2}{6^2}+\cdots \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(n)}{n^2}
\end{align}
$$

Here $a(n)$ is the number of unordered ways to factor $n$, for example $12^{-2}$ will appear as $2^{-4}3^{-2},2^{-2}6^{-2},3^{-2}4^{-2}$ and $12^{-2}$, so $a(12)=4$.

This $a(n)$ isn't multiplicative, so this expansion does not yield an Euler product in the sense of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product).

Of course there are products over the primes that equal $2$, e.g. $\prod_p (1+\delta_{2,p})$ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta, but I don't think that's what you meant.